# Concurrency in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, multithreading, concurrency

I am currently trying to implement the [Bully Algorithm](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~cs554/NOTES/Ch6-Election.pdf) in NodeJS. In this algorithm, I have a while loop which, when called by the main script, check for the states of nodes. I would like to run the main file and the while loop simultaneously. Is there a way to do this ?

I know that in Python for example, we can use gevent and spawn(). Is there a way to achieve such thing in NodeJS ?

In Python, I have a group (self.pool) in which I 'push' self.check() which runs the while loop allowing me to check for nodes.

```
self.check_servers_greenlet = self.pool.spawn(self.check())
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to achieve such thing in NodeJS ?

Yes, you use [child processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). You can interact with the child process via IPC, or sockets, or its `stdin`/`stderr`/`stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Use packages such as [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to run the same app with different entries

or

2. [child processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) which can be complicated a bit